# How do I get the tags in a struct through packages/packages?

Tags: go, reflection, code-generation

I want to fetch information about a struct to use in a custom go generator.
By using packages/packages I am able to fetch all fields from a struct and their types, I however can't figure out how to also fetch the tags for each field. The generator doesn't run in the same code base as the struct I try to read, so for as far as I know, I can't use reflection itself.

Example of what I have so far:

```
package models

type User struct {
    Email      string  `json:"email" binding:"email"`
    FirstName  string `json:"firstName" binding:"required"`
}
```

How I get the fields and their types:

```
cfg := &packages.Config{
        Mode: packages.NeedName | packages.NeedFiles | packages.NeedSyntax | packages.NeedTypes | packages.NeedTypesInfo,
    }
    pkgs, _ := packages.Load(cfg, "./models")
    pkg := pkgs[0]

    structInfo := pkg.Types.Scope().Lookup("User").Type().Underlying().(*types.Struct)
    for i := 0; i < structInfo.NumFields(); i++ {
        field := structInfo.Field(i)
        fieldType := field.Type()
        print("Field: ", field.Name(), " Type: ", fieldType.String())
    }
```

In reflect there is the possibility to get the Tag by using

```
fieldType.Tag().Get("json")
```

But this doesn't seem possible in results from packages/packages.
Is there a way to get the tags anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Tag`](https://pkg.go.dev/go/types@go1.20.1#Struct.Tag) method. And you can also use `reflect.StructTag` as a helper type to parse the individual tag values from the raw tag string.

```golang
tag := structInfo.Tag(i) // get the raw unparsed tag string
stag := reflect.StructTag(tag) // convert to reflect.StructTag
stag.Get("json") // get values from the tag
```

https://go.dev/play/p/INpOyL9rS_f